# Run bash script on every machine using nohup

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I have 70 servers and among them one is a main server from where I want to run one bash script(let's say abc.sh) on every server and this is not a one time execution. That script must be alive on every server untill I kill it.

So I wrote following a simple script on my main server but it does not work.

```
for ip in $(cat ip_address_list.txt)
do

        echo "Executing for $ip"
        ssh -i ~/sysadmin.pem -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no sysadmin@$ip "cd ~/; mkdir monitoring-api; cd ~/monitoring-api; /usr/bin/gsutil cp gs://sysadmin/abc.sh.; chmod +x abc.sh; nohup ./abc.sh &"
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]
        then
              echo "Execution successful"
        fi

done
```

So when I run this script it runs for first IP only and stuck there so I have to press ctrl + c to come out of it and soon as I press ctrl + c , abc.sh script gets terminated.
Can anyone tell me what is the issue here?

Comment: Unrelated: What is `cd ~/` and where does this monstrosity come from? Just use `cd` to get to your home directory.

Comment: How exactly it does not work? SSH executes *command* instead of remote shell, not by a shell.

Comment: This seems like a tool for the first time run. Once you have done your `mkdir`, `cp`, etc, you only need to run `nohup /path/abc.sh &`. BUT not clear what the problem is. Edit your Q to include exact (but redacted if required) text of output/errMsgs (don't post such info in comments! /-;!). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter script works for first ip only and stuck there, so I have to press ctrl + c to come out of it and as soon as I press ctrl + c , abc.sh gets terminated on respectiver server.

Comment: Please try https://shellcheck.net/ before asking for human assistance.

Comment: `nohup` does nothing useful; it is a completely purposeless tool. All it does is (1) redirect stdin from `/dev/null`; (2) redirect stdout to `nohup.out` if it's previously going to a TTY; (3) redirect stderr to `nohup.out` if it's previously going to a TTY; and (4) ignore HUP signals (which noninteractive shells already do anyhow).

Comment: (Also, remember that ssh doesn't create a tty by default when you pass it a command to run, so even if your local shell has its stdout attached to a real TTY, that doesn't mean the remote shell's stdout will see one!)

Comment: BTW, you tagged the question `bash` and `sh`. They're two different shells, not quite completely compatible with each other; pick one or the other. (Even when `sh` is a symlink to `bash`, bash turns off some features and changes behavior of others when started under the `sh` name).

Comment: Another note -- think about replacing this whole thing with `systemd-run`; that way the logs go the journal with all your other services. Or even better than that, a proper orchestration tool -- `chef`, `puppet`, etc

Answer (score 2):

Some pertinent facts:

- `nohup` only redirects stdin, stdout, and stderr when they were going to a TTY to begin with.
- `ssh host somecommand...` doesn't create a TTY unless you use the `-tt` argument to force it (as in: `ssh -tt host somecommand...`).

Instead of relying on `nohup` to do the right thing, just get rid of it (you don't get HUP signals sent by your terminal when you aren't running in a terminal at all in the first place -- so in a place where HUP signals are relevant you can use the bash builtin `disown -h` to disable them without needing nohup, but in your current situation they're moot to begin with).

```
remoteCmd() {
  mkdir -p ~/monitoring-api || exit
  cd ~/monitoring-api || exit
  /usr/bin/gsutil cp gs://sysadmin/abc.sh . || exit
  chmod +x abc.sh || exit
  ./abc.sh </dev/null >"abc.log.$$" 2>&1 &
}
ssh -i ~/sysadmin.pem -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "sysadmin@$ip" \
  "$(declare -f remoteCmd); remoteCmd"
```

The use of `</dev/null >"abc.log.$$" 2>&1` does the same thing as the only parts of `nohup` that are actually useful, while continuing to operate even when started in such a way as to not have an available TTY, *and* with a better-selected filename than the hardcoded default of `nohup.out`.

(Note that the use of `declare -f` above expects your local shell to be `bash`, *not* `sh`).

Comment: Maybe also mention https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor and [Why is testing ”$?” to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)